# Is there a better C# ECMAScript engine than ScriptControlClass?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-3.5, ecma262

Implementing the ScriptControlClass was extremely easy, unfortunately the side effects with the language implementation is really starting to worry me.   The goal was to have a language that was the same as the browser's JavaScript.  However, I am finding a difference in case sensitivity, function declarations and behavior of scoping between JavaScript and JScript.  The goal was to not have to train on multiple languages for the IT organizations, but rather standardize on JavaScript...

So that aside... What choices are available in C# to implement embedded JavaScript, besides ScriptControlClass?

Comment: What is "browser's java script"? There's ECMAScript spec, and IIRC JScript is conformant to that. It may have its extensions, and it may not implement some extensions that are commonly used in some browsers (say, Firefox), but that's another matter.

Comment: With IE, when writing JavaScript it is case sensitive. declaring a function AGE and a variable age will not conflict.  When using the ScriptControlClass that implements jScript, I get a conflict between the 2 ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RemObjects Script for .NET?](http://www.remobjects.com/roscript.aspx)

Comment: "RemObjects Script is in early development stages"

Comment: Short tests show that it is working fine. Not much documentation though, the only usefull i found is here: http://code.remobjects.com/p/roscript2/page/Using/

Answer (score 0):

[JScript.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a.aspx)